# Error trying to record audio using Python/Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, speech-recognition, pyaudio, python-sounddevice

I have tried pyaudio/sounddevice, and using them leads me to the error: **||PaMacCore (AUHAL)|| AUHAL component not found.Traceback (most recent call last):**. I think it has something to do with my mac not giving permission to terminal to use the microphone, and I have read a few questions about that, but there is no prompt in my security/privacy to grant terminal permission to microphone. I have a 2017 macbook pro 13inch with catalina. Thank you for your time.

[image]

I am using the following code:

```html
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")
frames = []
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to try changing the microphone permissions if you haven't already.

1. Open System Preferences and navigate to Security & Privacy -> Privacy and press on the lock to make changes. Once you have entered your password, look for the "Microphone" icon in the left panel and click on it. Then in the right panel where it says, "Allow the apps below to access your microphone," click the checkbox next to Terminal.
2. See what happens when you create a new user on the computer in the group "Administrator." You can do this by going to System Preferences again and navigating to Users & Groups. Then, click the lock again and enter your password to make changes. Once the lock is open, under "Login Options" in the left panel, click the + button. For the dropdown menu next to "New Account," make sure you select "Administrator." The rest of the account information is up to you. When you're done, click "Create User" and log into the new account. Then try and test your code again to see if it works in this account and/or try step number 1 in that account. You can delete the account later since it is for testing purposes. Just make sure you copy any data you want back over to your main account.